# Load more result with search text box

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**I have a Query for the below result**

```
SELECT students_marks.owners_id, SUM(students_marks.points) As marks 
 FROM students_marks INNER JOIN 
      users 
      ON students_marks.owners_id = users.u_id 
 WHERE (users.first_name like '%m%' or users.username like '%m%') 
 GROUP BY owners_id 
 order by marks desc 
 limit 2
```

### **Result of Query in below table**

**owners_id** | **marks**

```
1  | 18 
3  | 17 
2  | 17 
6  | 15 
10 | 4
```

** I want to show  result whose  marks below 17 only**

Comment: Hint: `HAVING sum(students_marks.points) < 17`

Comment: @stickybit you can use alias in `HAVING` clauses in MySQL

Comment: yes Working @stickybit

Comment: @Cid: I know. But I simply don't like that. With always using repeated expressions one doesn't fall over cases where aliases don't work.

Comment: @stickybit fair point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using conditions on agregates you have to use [HAVING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html).
Try the below query

```
SELECT students_marks.owners_id, SUM(students_marks.points) As marks 
 FROM students_marks INNER JOIN 
      users 
      ON students_marks.owners_id = users.u_id 
 WHERE (users.first_name like '%m%' or users.username like '%m%') 
 GROUP BY owners_id
 HAVING marks < 17 
 order by marks desc 
 limit 2
```